# Is it bad of my SSD to back it up everyday?

Tags: ssd, backup, windows-backup

I am making a full Image Backup everyday of my SDD which contains my OS and everything else. Will it damage my SSD if I do this backup everyday or perhaps make it slower over time? The backup is saved on my HDD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from an SSD is a no-wear action.  Writing to it does cause some wear. Your setup is OK, as far as causing wear to the SSD.

However, imagine if there was a fire or flood; both original and backup are ruined.  Consider off-site backup of your most important files.  What about lightning?  Consider backing up to NAS behind a surge protector in another part of the building.  What about robbery?  Off-site or hidden backup servers are reasonable protection against those.  Backup has many considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from SSD (backup) should not lead to any its harm, thus I do not see any issues.
You can read about SSD failures here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-warning-signs-ssd-break-fail/ but I think that HDD will fail first.